# Enabling/disabling ads depending on app status

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I would like my ads to be shown while my app is trialed and disappear when app is fully licensed.

Kookiz-

```
Private Sub PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

    If App.IsTrial Then
        AdControl1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible

    Else
        AdControl1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried but after that I realised that visibility is not everything. Under ad I have buttons and when someone tries to click on it.... he clicks ad that is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `IsEnabled` still shows the Control.

What you should do is add an empty container for the ad in your XAML file, like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
    <StackPanel x:Name="spAd" Grid.Row="0">
        <!--Ad will be placed here via the code-->
    </StackPanel>   
</Grid>
```

Then in the `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` event handler, if `IsTrial` equals `true`, instanciate the `AdControl` and add it to the View:

```
AdControl _adControl = new AdControl();

// Use your real Application ID and Ad Unit ID here
_adControl.ApplicationId = "test_client";
_adControl.AdUnitId = "Image480_80"; 

_adControl.Width = 480;
_adControl.Height = 80;

spAd.Children.Add(_adControl);
```

Comment: I get that error: 'AdModel' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. 

And what is AdModel? any example of it ?

Comment: Hmm, now ad doesn't show up in both ways. Are you sure this code will make the adcontrol make itself?

Comment: Yes, that code should work, I use it in one of my apps. Are you sure that the AdControl container is visible? If it still doesn't work, you should register to the `AdControlError` event and look at the `e.ErrorCode` and `e.ErrorDescription`.

Comment: Maybe... Hmmm , in the .xaml page should there be anything more than that you pasted here?  <StackPanel x:Name="spAd" Grid.Row="0">
        <!--Ad will be placed here via the code-->
    </StackPanel>

Comment: No, that should be enough. Try to add something like a TextBlock in the StackPanel to make sure its content is visible.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is the reason I'm using vb.net? I just converted your code to vb.

Comment: @OlivierPayen Why not adding the ad control in the stackpanel directly in the xaml, then just switch the visibility from the code behind?

Comment: I thought about it. I just have buttons under the ad, so when someone uses trial- it's ok, but when someone uses a full version app he doesn't see ad, but when he wants to click on button ... he clicks ad :D because it's like transparent. Is there any way to "disable" ad?

Comment: @KooKiz I think that it is better for performance since it won't load the Ad control unnecessarily.

Comment: yea I think it's the best way. But it doesn't work for me ;( I don't know why.

Comment: If you set the visibility to collapsed, the control won't be rendered, so I don't believe it'll have any noticeable impact performance-wise. Just saying.

Comment: The funniest thing is that setting visibility doesn't work too :D look at my code kookiz (question)